# qmake equivalent of cmake execute_process()

Tags: c++, cmake, qmake

I have a project using CMake where I get the current git hash via:

```
if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND git log -1 --format=%H
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_HASH
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
else()
    set(GIT_COMMIT_HASH "unknown")
endif()

add_definitions("-DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\"")
```

is there an equivalent way of doing this with qmake?

Comment: why would you like to switch to qmake?

Comment: It is a different project which was created using qt creator and we do not want to change everything to cmake now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
exists( $$PWD/.git) {
    GIT_COMMIT_HASH = $$system(git log -1 --format=%H)
}else{
    GIT_COMMIT_HASH = "unknown"
}

DEFINES += GIT_COMMIT_HASH=\\\"$$GIT_COMMIT_HASH\\\"
```

works for me. Currently tested on Linux, I'll test it later on Windows.